# Filter log for a location but allow passing request to proxy

Tags: nginx, logging, filter

I know how to filter logs for a location:

```
# inside a http block
log_format filter '0.0.0.0 - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request"'
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent '
                  '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

# Inside a server block
location = /my/sensitive/location {
  access_log log/access.log filter;
}
```

Now, if I have an app server that should usually process the above filtered location the request will be processed by nginx alone instead and not forwarded to the app server.

Simplified config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  # ...

  root /my/website/root;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app-server;

  location = /my/sensitive/location {
    access_log log/access.log filter;
  }

  location @app-server {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://my_local_server;
  }
}
```

I can't put the `location` block inside my `location @app-server` block. I can't convert that above `location` block to an `if` block and put that inside the `@app-server` block.

So, how can I filter the logs for a location that is being handled by an app server through `proxy_pass`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to just extract the necessary proxy configuration to a snippet and include that in the various locations as needed. Example:

In `nginx/snippets/proxy.conf`:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;

proxy_pass http://my_local_server;
```

In `nginx/sites-available/my-host.conf`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  # ...

  root /my/website/root;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app-server;

  location = /my/sensitive/location {
    access_log log/access.log filter;
    include snippets/proxy.conf;
  }

  location @app-server {
    include snippets/proxy.conf;
  }
}
```

However, what I actually ended up doing was to just enable the filtered log for the entire server block since almost all of the requests would need filtering anyway:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  # ...

  access_log log/access.log filter;

  root /my/website/root;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app-server;

  location @app-server {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://my_local_server;
  }
}
```